# How do I make this paypal button centered and bigger

Tags: html, paypal

I am working on a project and want to know how to make the "Buy Now" part of my paypal button to be directly underneath the "Number of Tickets" part of the button, (or vice versa with "Number of Tickets" directly over "Buy Now").  As you can see, it is off and I have tried every that I could think of to make it look right, but have had no success.  Also, can I make the overall form bigger?

Please let me know if you can help,

Thanks

[PayPal Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDBjh.png)

Code:

```html
<form method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="9QRP36HGU9DP6">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Number of Tickets">Number of Tickets</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
<option value="1">1 $20.00 USD</option>
<option value="2">2 $40.00 USD</option>
<option value="3">3 $60.00 USD</option>
<option value="4">4 $80.00 USD</option>
<option value="5">5 $100.00 USD</option>
<option value="6">6 $120.00 USD</option>
<option value="7">7 $140.00 USD</option>
<option value="8">8 $160.00 USD</option>
<option value="9">9 $180.00 USD</option>
<option value="10">10 $200.00 USD</option>
</select> </td></tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The button and the card indicators below it are just one picture: https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif

The only thing you can do is crop the image to remove the white space around it and resize it to match your design.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form method="post" target="_top" class="center-this-stuff">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="9QRP36HGU9DP6" />
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Number of Tickets" />Number of Tickets
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select name="os0">
            <option value="1">1 $20.00 USD</option>
            <option value="2">2 $40.00 USD</option>
            <option value="3">3 $60.00 USD</option>
            <option value="4">4 $80.00 USD</option>
            <option value="5">5 $100.00 USD</option>
            <option value="6">6 $120.00 USD</option>
            <option value="7">7 $140.00 USD</option>
            <option value="8">8 $160.00 USD</option>
            <option value="9">9 $180.00 USD</option>
            <option value="10">10 $200.00 USD</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" />
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1" />
  </form>

  <style>
    .center-this-stuff {
      display: flex;
      align-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
  </style>
</body>

</html>
```

Here I created a class and put it on the parent element then I used Flexbox CSS properties to center everything.

Use flexbox to position things around your page